# Not able to save form data into database in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have created a scaffold name project and created another scaffold named 
stage. There is one to many associate between project and stage. like each project will have multiple stages. I am able to render stage form but i am not able to save data into stage table of the database.
[this error i get on saving stage form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6ViO.png)

stage form.html.erb

```
<%= form_with(model: stage, url: [@project, stage], local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if @stage.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(stage.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this stage from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% stage.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

<div class="row select-date-wrapper">
  <div class="field columns large-6">
    <%= form.label :stage %>
    <%= form.text_field :stage %>
  </div>

  <div class="field columns large-3">
    <%= form.label :planned_start_date %>
    <%= form.date_select :planned_start_date, class: 'select-date' %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit 'Create', :class=>"button primary small" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

stage_controller.rb

```
  def index
    @stages = Stage.all
  end

  def new
    @stage = Stage.new
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  end

  def create
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @stage = @project.stages.build(stage_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @stage.save
        format.html { redirect_to @stage, notice: 'Stage was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @stage }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @stage.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

model project.rb

```
has_many :stages
```

model stage.rb

```
  #belongs_to :project
  has_many :tasks
```

routes.rb

```
  resources :projects do
    resources :stages
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
if @stage.save
  format.html { redirect_to project_stage_path(@project, @stage), notice: 'Stage was successfully created.' }
  format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @stage }
else
  format.html { render :new }
  format.json { render json: @stage.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

please change `url: [@project, stage]` to `url: stages_path`

always try to make controller name plural. `stages_controller`